How can I know which folder/file is currently being scanned by Microsoft's Antimalware Service Executable?
I see that the Microsoft's Antimalware Service Executable is taking a fair amount of CPU:

How can I know which folder/file is currently being scanned by Microsoft's Antimalware Service Executable?

Possible duplicate here

You could use Process Monitor and filter to only include actions from process with name MsMpEng.exe, then check the Path column to know which  files/folders it accesses. Add filter for Operation as well to only include ReadFile.
Of course not all the files are scanned by the process. E.g. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\mpenginedb.db-shm is often accessed as it's some kind of internal database. You could filter out (exclude) all the repetitive paths like that for more accurate results.
